# Converting A Scrollable DIV Table To Remove Display Inline-Block Without Losing The Scrollbar

Tags: html, css, html-table, scrollbar

```css
.Main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.Row {
  white-space: nowrap;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.Cell {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<DIV class="Main">
  <DIV class="Row">
    <DIV class="Cell">BLANK</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 1</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 2</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 3</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 4</DIV>
  </DIV>
  <DIV class="Row">
    <DIV class="Cell">BLANK</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 1</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 2</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 3</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 4</DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

What I want to do is change the current existing code so that I can get rid of the inline-block parameter. As you know, whenever inline-block is used, there will be a space placed in between adjoining DIVs that can only be removed by code hacking: by inserting a comment tag, returning to the next line before closing the tag, applying negative margins, setting the font-size to zero, or skipping the closing tags altogether. Each one of these hacks results in a caveat, such as negative margins not being exact depending on browser, or font-size zero inadvertently hideing whatever text is occupying the cell (unless it is inside a SPAN container), but nothing compares to this catch: *changing the display parameter from inline-block to something else instantly results in the loss of the scroll bar*. How can I get rid of the inline-block DIV while avoiding code tricks without being forced to give up the scrollbar?

You will notice the Main DIV uses dynamic width. Many of the solutions I have found on the web and in here recommend that I use fixed width in pixels if I want to make the DIV scrollable. My preference for this problem is to retain dynamic width.

**EDIT**: Per Insync's request, I have added a new set of code to help solve a related inquiry. Suppose I wanted to add a static column to the left of the table; that way the headings can stay displayed without having to scroll back just to see what each row stands for. If I try to change the Main width to 100%, I also lose the scrollbar.

```css
.Container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.Child {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.MainTest {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.RowTest {
  display: flex;
}

.CellTest {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<DIV class="Container">

  <DIV class="Child">Static Column (Should be 250px)</DIV>

  <DIV class="Child">
    <DIV class="MainTest">
      <DIV class="RowTest">
        <DIV class="CellTest">Heading 1</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Heading 2</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Heading 3</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Heading 4</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Heading 5</DIV>
      </DIV>
      <DIV class="RowTest">
        <DIV class="CellTest">Entry 1</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Entry 2</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Entry 3</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Entry 4</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Entry 5</DIV>
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </DIV>

</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

Simply add `overflow: auto` to the second `.Child`:

```css
.Child:nth-child(2) {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Try it:

```css
.Child:nth-child(2) {
  overflow: auto;
}


/* Demo only */

.Container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.Child {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.MainTest {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.RowTest {
  display: flex;
}

.CellTest {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<DIV class="Container">
  <DIV class="Child">Static Column (Should be 250px)</DIV>
  <DIV class="Child">
    <DIV class="MainTest">
      <DIV class="RowTest">
        <DIV class="CellTest">Heading 1</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Heading 2</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Heading 3</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Heading 4</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Heading 5</DIV>
      </DIV>
      <DIV class="RowTest">
        <DIV class="CellTest">Entry 1</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Entry 2</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Entry 3</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Entry 4</DIV>
        <DIV class="CellTest">Entry 5</DIV>
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

### Original answer

You can use `display: flex` on `.Row` and set `.Cell`'s `flex-shrink`
to `0`:

```css
.Row {
  display: flex;
}

.Cell {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Also, note that `table-layout` [only works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#formal_definition) for `table` and `inline-table` elements.

Try it:

```css
.Main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.Row {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.Cell {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<DIV class="Main">
  <DIV class="Row">
    <DIV class="Cell">BLANK</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 1</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 2</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 3</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 4</DIV>
  </DIV>
  <DIV class="Row">
    <DIV class="Cell">BLANK</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 1</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 2</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 3</DIV>
    <DIV class="Cell">Move 4</DIV>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: While applying this code to my web page, I stumbled upon a new problem. Suppose I wanted to add a static column to the left of the table; that way the headings can stay displayed without having to scroll back just to see what each row stands for. If I try to change the Main width to 100%, I also lose the scrollbar. What can I do to still keep that 100% if I wanted to add a static column?

Comment: @Wammy Could you add that as an edit to the question? I find it hard to visualize the new layout.

Comment: The method I am using to make the DIVs side by side to mimic a static column is "flex," sourced from this web page: https://coder-coder.com/display-divs-side-by-side/

Comment: @Wammy Updated. See if it works.

Comment: It does work, but there is one problem. The first column must be able to take an exact pixel amount (in the example, it's 250px). I tried adjusting both column's width with fixed pixels and a percentage to see if I can get that in; neither move works. I'll continue to go over the problem. I've uploaded an image to show what the HTML is supposed to look like: [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/CachRF8.png)

Comment: @Wammy Set `flex: 0 0 250px` to the first `.Child` then.